seperator ="§" should be a single byte character, but is 2 bytes long error in Python to read csv in Polars dataframe
Following code I'm using to read CSV file into Polars data frame where my csv is having § (section sign) as separator .
import polars as po

po_df = po.read_csv(<*full file path*>, separator= '§', has_header=True, quote_char='"', encoding='utf8')


print(po_df.columns)

read_csv throwing following error -
"seperator ="§" should be a single byte character, but is 2 bytes long"

tried to run with different encoding but it's not working.
Any help to resolve this error would be much appreciated.

What encoding(s) have you tried?  For both the CSV file, and your script?

When you use a non-utf-8 encoding, polars will read it as whatever you specify and then write it to BytesIO with utf8 encoding before reading it with its native rust reader. It doesn't convert your separator in this way so it still fails. To get around that you can simply do what polars was going to do anyway except you also replace your separator with something else. I'm using a control character here so I wouldn't think there'd be a collision.
from io import BytesIO
with open(YOUR_FILE,'r',encoding='latin-1') as s, BytesIO() as b:
    b.write(s.read().replace('§','\x1f').encode('utf-8'))
    b.seek(0)
    df=pl.read_csv(b,separator='\x1f', has_header=True, quote_char='"')


The character you're using as a separator '§' can't be encoded into a single byte in UTF-8. If you run the following, you'll see that it prints two bytes:
print('§'.encode('utf-8'))  # or alternatively: print(bytes('§', 'utf-8'))
# prints: b'\xc2\xa7'

Whereas a typical separator like a comma ',' only occupies one byte.
If you use the encoding latin-1 instead, the '§' character only occupies one byte \xa7, but I suspect your CSV file will need to use the same encoding.

Hello, I tried with latin-1 but same error persists. My file also has latin-1 encoding.

Hmm...I wonder if this is a limitation with polars itself then...

polars only supports utf-8

@DeanMacGregor - the doc says When using other encodings than utf8 or utf8-lossy, the input is first decoded in memory with python. So, other encodings are supported. It doesn't mention how that decoded string is then used - perhaps its utf-8 encoded and passed to a C parser. Wild guess there.

polars is written in rust. The rust side of things doesn't support non-utf-8. I neglected to double check that the python side wouldn't decode it. That said, it still expects the separator to be a valid 1 byte utf-8 character. They could read it if they don't use that as the separator and then subsequently split the columns up manually.

@DeanMacGregor Good info! This is definitely an interesting edge case

Polars csv_read restricts separator to a single byte
separator 
     Single byte character to use as separator in the file.

This is common for parsers, especially C parsers, that parse byte strings and work with UTF-8 encodings as long as the separator is in the ASCII range. § encodes to b'\xc2\xa7' in UTF-8 and so it won't work.
Assuming you can't switch separators, you can switch parsers. For instance, use pandas as an intermediate.
import polars as po
import pandas as pd

po_df = po.from_pandas(pd.read_csv(<*full file path*>, separator= '§',
    has_header=True, quote_char='"', encoding='utf8', engine="python"))

print(po_df.columns)

There are many other CSV parsers out there - for instance, the pyarrow CSV reader may be a good option.
